# Проблемы с указанием шрифта в Label Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, шрифты

Когда я указываю шрифт, который содержит 2 слова, мне выводит ошибку такую:

```
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "Bold"
```

Вот сам код:

```
txt = Label(text="Test fonts", font="ProunX Bold 20")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708182/changing-font-style-in-canvas-is-giving-me-a-error-when-font-is-not-one-word-pyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то сначала идёт размер шрифта, а потом уже полужирный и курсив. То есть вы должны его прописать так:

```
txt = Label(text="Test fonts", font="ProunX 20 bold")
```